# How is it possible that a violin has a very different color on parts of its body from the rest of it?

Tags: violin

How it looks as shown below:

[image]

The owner told me that it is due to the positioning of chinrest, but it does not explain the color difference on the top left. In addition there are also such color difference on the top plate.

Could e.g. sun, humidity and temperature be the cause of such phenomenon?

Comment: How old is it? Fake antiquing is a lot easier to rub off than actually being old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anytime an instrument like this comes into contact with our skin, there's a risk of skin oils and general friction interfering with the look of the instrument.

The chin rest explains the discoloration at the bottom of the picture, but I would argue that the top left of the picture is a common place for the violinist's left hand to hold onto and adjust the instrument, which could cause that same discoloration over time.

Comment: As a corollary,  if you care about your axe,  use soft cloth to clean every region where a chin rest or any skin contacts the wood.  Further, wipe rosin off the strings as well as any rosin dust on the top plate.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I find it charming and cute that musicians call violins "axe". You brightened up my day.

Comment: @RedSonja  it's a generic name (slang) for pretty much whatever instrument you play :-) .